# How to reverse Scrollbar of the HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, xml, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to make an `HoziontalScrollView` with items :

[image]

When I move the `scrollbar` to the left, the `HoziontalScrollView` goes right and vice versa, which will make the user confused about how to use the scrollbar to scroll instead of moving finger over the `HoziontalScrollView`

XML :

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/outer_windows_background"
    android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_track_horizontal"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_photo_editor">

    //ITEMS

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not hide the scrollbar instead? 
 `android:scrollbars="none"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
HorizontalScrollView hsv;
hsv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        event.setLocation(-1*event.getX(), event.getY());
        hsv.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }
})
```